# Can I use my BLU M8L Plus tablet to make calls using my SIM minutes?

Tags: calls, tablet, blu

I currently have to use my BLU M8L Plus (4G) tablet as my phone but am unable to use my minutes to make phone calls. When I use WiFi or data to make calls, it sounds horrible and also not easy to get verification codes. I prefer using my minutes.

What hacks or apps can I use to call using mins? Any ideas?